# Help my danios stomach is huge and looks like it's going to explode!

Tags: health, fish, danio

So i have a tank of about 15 litres and I have had a Danio and a guppy for a year. Nitrate levels are low and there isn't any ammonia, also the water ph is normal. My brother fed the danio,goldfish pellets and somehow she digested it. She looks awful and from one side it looks like her stomach is about to explode, also if you can see there is some brown thing inside of it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news is that it does not look like dropsy. I would try to treat the fish like it is constipated. Put a single (thawed) pea and see if she eats it.

Monitor and observe. If the fish gets worse, start treatment as if it is injured with melafix.